# How color each tab of a TTabSet of Delphi in a different color?

Tags: delphi

How color each tab of a TTabSet of Delphi in a different color?

I would like to change the color of a specific tab in a TTabSet component. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to owner-draw the tabs manually.  `TTabSet` has an `OnDrawTab` event for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I typed TTabSheet  but I meant TTabSet

Comment: `TTabSet` has an `OnDrawTab` event as well.